# Add "invisible" decimal places to end of number?

Tags: python-3.x

I am printing a "Table" to the console. I will be using this same table structure for several different variables. However as you can see from **Output** below, the lines don't all align.

One way to resolve it would be to increase the number of decimal places (e.g. 6.730000 for Standard Deviation) which would push the line into place.

However, I do not want this many decimal places.

**Is it possible to add extra 0s to the end of a number, and make these invisible?**

I am planning on using this table structure for several variables, and the length of Mean, Stddev, and Median will likely never be more than 6 characters.

**EDIT - I would really like to ensure that each value which appears in the table will be 6 characters long, and if it is not 6 characters long, add additional "invisible" zeros.**

**Input**

```
# Create and structure Table to store descriptive statistics for each variable.

 subtitle = "|   Mean    |   Stddev   |   Median  |" 
 structure = '|  {:0.2f}  |  {:0.2f}   | {:0.2f}   |' 
 lines = '=' * len(subtitle)

# Print table.

print(lines)
print(subtitle)
print(lines)
print(structure.format(mean, std, median))  
print(lines)
```

**Output:**

```
======================================
|   Mean    |   Stddev   |   Median  |
======================================
|  181.26  |  6.73   | 180.34   |
======================================
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't really figure this out - but found a workaround.

I just did the following:

```
"|  {:^6}  |  {:^6}   | {:^6}   | {:^6}   | {:^6}   |"
```

This keeps the width between `|` consistent.

Comment: And if you want to have consistent number of decimal places, you can have `{:^6.2f}`. The 6 is the total length of the field (including the decimal point) and the .2f gives 2 decimal points after the decimal. Change the values to whatever makes your table the most aesthetically pleasing